# Arrays suddenly return empty on react javascript

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Well I'm trying to obtain a display_name from a item that hasn't got that property but has tokenId, so I use a gameData.json to match the IDS, which is a property that the object has, and then rescue the display_name.

The function works sometimes, and sometimes it returns all my arrays as empty.

This is the useEffect code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const orderNFTByDisplayName = async () => {
      fetchMarketItems.map((element) => {
        tokenIdsArray.push(element.tokenId);
        console.log("tokenIdsArray pushed");
        const nftDetails = {
          date: dateFormat(element.updatedAt),
          collection: element.nftContract,
          tags: [element.seller, element.sold],
          price: element.price / ("1e" + 18),
          transaction_hash: element.transaction_hash,
          display_name: null,
        };
        nftDetailsArray.push(nftDetails);
        console.log("nftDetailsArray pushed ", nftDetailsArray);
        return nftDetails;
      });
      //nftTokenIds: tokenIdsArray[index],
      const displays = await getDisplayName(tokenIdsArray);
      console.log("displays are", displays);
      setDisplayNames(displays);
      console.log("Display names are", displayNames);
      //mapNFTs.forEach((element, index) => element.push(displayNames[index]));
    };
    orderNFTByDisplayName();
    for (let i = 0; i < nftDetailsArray.length; i++) {
      nftDetailsArray[i].display_name = displayNames[i];
    }
    console.log("nftDetails Array is ", nftDetailsArray);
    setData(nftDetailsArray);
    console.log("data is", data);
  }, []);
```

This is the getDisplayName function:

```
    const getDisplayName = async (tokenId) => {
    console.log("token id is", tokenId);
    const result = await Moralis.Cloud.run("BatchGetItemIdByTokenId", {
      tokenIds: [Number(tokenId)],
    });
    const payload = result.Payload;
    const itemIdsArray = [];
    const itemsArray = [];
    const displayNamesArray = [];
    payload.forEach((element) => itemIdsArray.push(element.itemId));
    console.log("itemIdsArray are ", itemIdsArray);
    for (let i = 0; i < itemIdsArray.length; i++) {
      const gameDataItems = gameData.item_table.filter(
        (element) => element.id === itemIdsArray[i]
      );
      itemsArray.push(gameDataItems);
    }
    console.log("itemsArray is", itemsArray);
    itemsArray.forEach((element, index) =>
      displayNamesArray.push(element[index].display_name)
    );
    console.log("displayNamesArray isa", displayNamesArray);
    return displayNamesArray;
  };
```

and this is Chrome's output:
[Chrome's Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIBep.png)

[Empty Arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78GAP.png)

Comment: On the runs where everything is empty, what does your console.log("displays are", displays); look like?

Comment: displays are Array(0)length: 0[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
an empty array, please check the image I attached.